# How do you do "git checkout -- .emacs" using magit?

Tags: magit, git

When a file (like .emacs for example) is modified in a Git repository, if I want to `git pull` git refuses to do so because I have a modified file. Git proposes to remove the modification by doing

```
git checkout -- .emacs
```

But how do you do that using Magit ? I have [seen](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) that `--` is the equivalent of `--ignore-skip-worktree-bits` but I don't see this option in Magit.

Comment: `--` just separates options from file names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either stash the modifications with <kbd>z</kbd> or kill the modifications with <kbd>k</kbd>.

The latter, with point at `.emacs`, is the equivalent of checking out the latest/unmodified revision of that file. You can also apply it to the entire list of modified files.